# nginx on azure remote server works with simple index.php but not on project

Tags: nginx, azure

I'm trying to deploy a project on an ubuntu 22.04 LTS azure remote with nginx.

First I tried to deploy a simple index.html. It worked well.

Then, I tried to deploy a simple index.php. It didn't work until I realized I needed to install php (in my case, I installed 8,1 version) on server and install php8.1-fpm . Then, my simple index.php on /var/www/html worked.

Then, I tried to deploy my project. These are the steps I followed:

1. I cloned my repo on /var/www/html. Its name is imagenes (a laravel repo, where index.php is in folder /public)
2. I created /etc/nginx/sites-available/imagenes.conf

```
server{
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/html/imagenes/public;
index index.html index.html index.php;
server_name myDnsName;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

3. I executed

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/imagenes /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

to copy my conf in sites-enabled

4. I restarted my server: the served was working
5. I tested the syntax with sudo nginx -t: the syntax was ok

When I go to my DNS name of my Azure server, it says the page is not working: HTTP Error 500

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also installed php-fpm?

Comment: I installed php-fpm as well, as I say in the 3rd paragraph

Comment: Is php running? `systemctl status php8.1-fpm`. Sorry i overread that

Comment: no problem. It's my first post as well, so maybe it's not well structured. 
it says it is active and running

Comment: Please show us your logs, read [ask], and provide all the necessary information for a business related communication that impacts your business related question or issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example config for Lavarel maybe it's helpful

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/example.com/public;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#nginx

And you also need to install these php modules

```
sudo apt install php-mbstring php-xml php-bcmath
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It started working after that. @Turdie